# Отсутствие переводов при в функционале вопросов в закладках

Tags: дефект, локализация, профиль-участника, страница-учётной-записи, закладки

При нажатии на закладку возле вопроса можно увидеть такое сообщение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если нажмем Управлять:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и такое если нажмем из вопроса снова на символ закладки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше если переходим в дашборд пользователя и переходим в закладки то вкладка имеет такую строку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в самих закладках видим такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и вот такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если получится, то добавлю часть переводов :)